# Boot Win10 tablet with USB stick and access NTFS C: partition

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, uefi, bootable-media, winsxs

I have messed up with C:\Windows\WinSxS directory in a Win10 32 bit tablet.
Specifically I renamed "Manifests" dir into "Manifests2" and moved all 
"x86_*" dirs into a subdir "x86"

Now it won't boot, it goes BSOD (critical process died) a few seconds after 
the manufacturer boot logo.

All I need to do is to boot with a live pendrive, access C: NTFS partition, 
rename and move those modified WinSxS dirs and it should be good to go.

Tablet has only one micro USB port, so I'm using a USB-OTG cable to connect 
USB pendrive, swap it with a keyboard when I need to input commands since I 
don't have a USB hub atm.

Being Win10 it has UEFI, I can access UEFI shell but I don't think it's 
much use.

Pressing power+volume button I have access to boot menu where I can boot 
from file, this must be "bootia32.efi".
This way I succesfully live booted a Rufus created pendrive with Kali Linux 
in text rescue mode, got into shell,
fdisk -l gives me all the partitions, windows is on "mmcblk1p3",
I try to mount ntfs /dev/mmcblk1p3 on media/win but no luck.

I think the simplest way is find a way to boot a Windows / Dos pendrive that 
can access directly NTFS C: partition without all that Linux mount thing.
A cmd terminal will be enough for the rename / move operations I have to do.

What can I use to build such a USB bootable media?

Comment: It is entirely possible that the tablet has disk encryption enabled which is why you cannot read the partition. The Windows Media Creation tool should be able to create a bootable Windows USB that you can try and do some recovery from https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 You will have to create the media on a working machine though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you decide to rename the folders?

Comment: I succesfully moved all the msil_* dirs into \msil, moved nearly all x86*_ in \x86, then I was left back with about eighty x86 dirs I couldn't move the first time. After I managed to move even those 80 to the subdir. I think what I had not to do was to rename Manifest. These are my experiments to slim down system (not always successful as you may have noticed...)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve with [Lazesoft Recovery Suite](http://www.lazesoft.com/lazesoft-recovery-suite-free.html)

- installed on another PC
- Burn CD/USB Disk
- Select Windows version (Win 10 32 bit in my case)
- it will automatically download relevant files*
- Put a shady 1 GB USB Flash in
- Create USB bootable media

Then on my tablet

- got a USB hub**
- got a USB keyboard
- got a USB OTG cable
- boot from file (select USB filesystem)
- loaded the live environment
- launched the file manager and did the rename / move operations I knew

*The Recovery Environment footprint on the USB media was around 250 megs, so much less than standard WinPE. Also for this reason the download was fast.

**I tried to do without USB hub, so starting with USB media in, then swapping with keyboard, but didn't work. It worked with Kali Linux altough.

Comment: But will it work with a non-shady USB stick?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You said that you used a shady USB stick, so I was jokingly asking if it had to be a shady USB stick.

Comment: ok, I forgot I used the s word ;-)